# Php.ini gives different results

Tags: php

I have a quick question. When I check the `upload_max_filesize` within my Cpanel, It says the following:

`File Uploads upload_max_filesize Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.  50M`

It doesn't show me the full php.ini because my host doesn't allow me to access it.

But when I check with php `( var_dump(let_to_num(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'))); )` I get the following result: `Int(2097152) = 2Mb`

Just as notice, my uploader still doesn't allow files over 2mb.

Can anybody tell my why I get different results here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's there in htaccess file?

Comment: Nothing about file upload size, only about allowed extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to get an answer from the host. It was a bug.

Comment: Can you explain about thing about the bug, diagnosis and solution etc? others might also have this bug...

Comment: I'm sorry @martin bug was on hostingside. They fixes it and I don't exactly know what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to open a support ticket to your hosting.

Another option is an error in Cpanel that shows 'post_max_size' instead of 'upload_max_filesize' from php.ini

Comment: It's to big to show a snippet, It's de pdw_file_uploader